# Alternate Access Mappings problem

Tags: alternate-access-mapping, variations

I have my SharePoint 2010 site, with variations, configured to run on HTTP and HTTPS. In my AAM it looks like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com
https://www.mysite.com
```

Both are set to the same zone - Internet.

The problem is when I navigate to the site using 'mysite.com', I get a error on the page when it hits 'VariationRoot.aspx' that the page is not found.

I have added '**http ://mysite.com**' to the AAM, but the site uses cookies, and when a user for whatever reason, switches from '**http ://www.mysite.com**' to '**http ://mysite.com**', the cookie data is not being used by SharePoint.

Any suggestions on how I can include '**http ://mysite.com**' to the AAM without having the issue of not being able to read the cookie previously set by '**http ://www.mysite.com**'?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this thread : http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/66d04689-e37f-4709-8145-ae7387fc50ef/extend-sharepoint-web-application-with-or-without-www

It seems you can add "mysite.com" to your access mapping, so requests will be transferred to www.mysite.com. I haven't tested it though.

Comment: I have added it to AAM, but the issue is the cookies are not being read when a user switches from www.mysite.com to mysite.com

Comment: Well, maybe you could configure your cookies, but I haven't done this myself. If I were you I would try to avoid switches between www.mysite and mysite.